# Is there a way to set Jacoco as default code coverage tool in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-coverage, jacoco

As the title suggests, I would like to know if there's a way to set Jacoco as default code coverage tool in IntelliJ, meaning that I don't want to edit my run configuration to Jacoco every time I create a new  project, which is what I currently have to do, because everytime I create a new project, it automatically uses the IntelliJ code coverage.

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-code-coverage-measurement.html ?

Comment: @GhostCat yes, that link doesn't describe changing coverage tools. There is also another article on jetbrains.com on how to change coverage tools, but this only changes it in my current project, and doesn't set it as default.

Comment: Just in case you dont get a response here: consider posting in the JetBrains forums. Typically, it doesn't take long until a JetBrains employee or hardcore IntelliJ users comes back with ideas.

Comment: Good idea, i'll do that